# receive value of shared SharedPreferences value from another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

i have this code for get value of SharedPreferences from edittext and then send it to other activity   somehow i cannot use it from other activity what i miss in my code any suggestions 
thanks in advance

-thats my first activity that for get SharedPreferences from edittext and i want to send value from it to the second activity

```
public class NationalId extends Activity {
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

final Context context = this;
private Button button;
private TextView result;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_national_id);

    // components from main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    String n  = userInput.getText().toString();
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString(Name, n);
                                    editor.commit();
                                    // edit text
                                    result.setText(userInput.getText());
                                    Toast.makeText(NationalId.this,"saved:"+n,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

and here my second activity that i want receive the value in

```
public class receive extends Activity {



private Button button;
private EditText etPhoneno;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opreator_mobily);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
    etPhoneno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Name",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String value = prefs.getString("n", "0");
    // add button listener\
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(receive.this,"saved:"+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? do you want to pass your `edittext` String value to another activity? or you have some value saved in `SharedPreferences` and you want to use it in that 2nd activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second activity you are trying to get your sharedpreferences instance with different name and also getting your saved value with different key.

Replace this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Name", MODE_PRIVATE);
final String value = prefs.getString("n", "0");
```

with

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
final String value = prefs.getString("nameKey", "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace these two below lines

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Name",MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String value = prefs.getString("n", "0");
```

with these lines

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
final String value = prefs.getString("nameKey", "0");
```